# GDI+ GraphicsContainer doesn't work

Tags: c++, graphics, mfc, gdi+

it seems GraphicsContainer doesn't work if I set Page Unit into Inch.

So I tested like the code below.

[image]

In this code, I draw 2 ellipses - before(1st) and after(2nd) the Container begins.
If container works, the circle's color should be Blue. but it is still green. it means the second drawing code under BeginContainer() doesn't work at all.

this never happened when I set page unit into UnitPixel, or UnitWorld, except UnitInch..
What is the reason? is there something wrong I missed? How can I solve it?

```
CPaintDC dc(this); CRect rec; GetClientRect(&rec);
Gdiplus::Graphics g(dc.GetSafeHdc());
g.SetPageUnit(UnitInch);
float dx = 2; float dy = 4;
REAL DpiX = g.GetDpiX(); REAL DpiY = g.GetDpiY();
Matrix flipMatrix(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,-1.0f,-dx,dy);
g.SetTransform(&flipMatrix);
g.TranslateTransform((rec.Width()/2)/DpiX ,(rec.Height()/2)/DpiY, Gdiplus::MatrixOrderAppend);
//Pen//
Gdiplus::Pen RedPen(Gdiplus::Color::Red, 0.1);
Gdiplus::Pen BluePen(Gdiplus::Color::Blue, 0.1);
Gdiplus::Pen GreenPen(Gdiplus::Color::Green, 0.1);
//Draw Cross
g.DrawLine(&GreenPen, PointF(dx-1.0f,dy+1.0f), PointF(dx+1.0f, dy-1.0f));
g.DrawLine(&GreenPen, PointF(dx+1.0f,dy+1.0f), PointF(dx-1.0f, dy-1.0f));
//Draw 1st Ellipse without Container
g.DrawEllipse(&RedPen, dx-1,dy-1, 2.0f,2.0f);
GraphicsContainer C;
//Start Container------
C=g.BeginContainer();
//Draw 2nd Ellipse within Container
g.DrawEllipse(&BluePen, dx-1,dy-1, 2.0f,2.0f);
//End Container 
g.EndContainer(C);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a call to `g.SetPageUnit(UnitInch)` earlier. Evidentally a second call to `g.SetPageUnit(Gdiplus::UnitInch)` is required after `BeginContainer`:

```
g.SetPageUnit(UnitInch);
...
GraphicsContainer C;
//Start Container------
C = g.BeginContainer();
g.SetPageUnit(Gdiplus::UnitInch); //<== put after g.BeginContainer
//Draw 2nd Ellipse within Container
g.DrawEllipse(&BluePen, dx - 1, dy - 1, 2.0f, 2.0f);
//End Container 
g.EndContainer(C);
```

If you don't call `SetPageUnit(Gdiplus::UnitInch)` after `BeginContainer`, you get a smaller circle in pixel units, and it will be at the wrong position because of the earlier transition in `UnitInch`.